What is the condition for a manifold defined by a smooth implicit function to be a closed manifold?
We have an implicit function which describes a manifold surface, and I want to know the conditions for the implicit function so that the manifold defined by the conditions is a closed manifold.
My first thought is that, assume we have a sufficiently large sphere, and let $s$ values outside the ball constantly greater than zero (the level set value), the manifold is closed?

For example, $s = f(x,y,z) = 0$, its zero-level set defines a surface.
(1) $s = x + y + z = 0$ is not closed.
(2) $s = tanh(x + y + z) = 0$ is not closed.
(3) $s = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 1 = 0$ is closed.
NOTE : it is generally defined on the entire domain $\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Some sufficient and practical conditions are also okay.
I want to know whether it is possible to just impose some sorts of mild constraints on the function so that the manifold is closed?

you want the function to be proper and $s$ to be a regular value (this is a  necessary-and-sufficient condition, but the one which is used in practice)

@user8268 Presumably you meant "this is not a necessary-and-sufficient condition"

@Didier I accidentally a word :(

Welcome to MSE! <> The term closed has two meanings for manifolds: topologically closed (the complement is open), and compact without boundary, which context suggests is meant. <> As for an exact condition for a level set to be a compact manifold, it's hard to imagine one that isn't tautological. Can you please edit the question to say more about why you're asking? Particularly, what class of functions $f$ might arise? Do you have information on the growth of $f$ at infinity? And so forth....
